# NSClassFromString Idea

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, nsobject

I'm currently trying to create objects from the NSClassFromString(NSString *) method.

What I want to be able to achieve is the following...

```
NSClassFromString(stringType) *pageController = nil;
```

Instead of the following...

```
UIViewController *pageController = nil;
```

So in other words, instead of using a UIViewController, I want to use the correct class. I want to be able to achieve the above without having to type the exact class.
I would normally write it like the following, but due to expansion of the application, it needs to change.

```
MPLandscapeImage *pageController = nil;
```

Is this possible and if so, how can I complete what is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Do this.

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(stringType);
// You have to use id here
id pageController = nil;
// And later
pageController = [[cls alloc] init];
```

Comment: By using id type it doesn't work as needed unfortunately! I'm sure there should be another way to achieve this...

Comment: Got it all working using the method above, was an issue with the way that `id` types handle views.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that.  you can use the id type for this.

However,  I would ask what you are trying to accomplish because circumventing the type system is often a Bad Idea(tm).

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use generics/templates in Objective C. Ain't gonna work. Use the id type instead, its much more applicable to what you are trying to do.